# SAP HANA DB login using JWT token

Tags: node.js, hana

Can I somehow log into the SAP HANA database from the 'hdbext' Node.JS module, using XSUAA as the IDP, and also the JWT bearer token?

I am able to write "'sessionVariable: XS_APPLICATIONUSER': hdbToken," and then the expression "SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT ('XS _APPLICATIONUSER') FROM DUMMY" returns the desired user.

But can I somehow connect so that the "SELECT SESSION_USER FROM DUMMY" statement returns the same user, and not the technical RT?

For example, similar functionality exists in HANA Studio, when we make a login with the "Authentication by current operating system user".

Answer (score 1):

Short anwser: **no**.

This was that way in HANA XS applications. But one of the major changes in architecture with XSA is single technical user for database access. This concept is visualized in the documentation in [this schema](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3ee5778bc2e4a089d3299b82ec762a7/2.0.01/en-US/f441ef17875741e29434a2b172afbce4.html).
[image: XSA Auth]

I think the main reason of this is all that issues that came from making app user to be a DBMS user resulting in high effort of security management for such multipurpose user. What I've met in some systems: when you have hundreds of users and some role that is assigned to lots of them is changed, then changes to that role takes too long time to update all the system tables with required information, that system can become unresponsible for some other operations.

You can check openSAP course [Software Development on SAP HANA (Update Q1/2019)](https://open.sap.com/courses/hana7/), Week 1, Unit 5 to get a brief description of security model.